# Minimum spanning tree containing a given edge after removing edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, max-flow

This is a part of an exam preparation. I know it has something to do with max-flow algorithm, but I'd be happy for a hint:

Let `G=(V,E)` an undirected connected graph, and let `w:E->R` a weight function, `e` an edge and `k > 0`. Describe an algorithm that determines whether we can remove at most `k` edges from the graph, so that `e` would belong to a minimum spanning tree of the new graph.

I think that a spanning tree is kind of a perfect matching. But how do I make it minimal that contains e and the right amount of other edges?

Comment: Did you mean spanning tree? There will be only one minimal spanning tree. So, find the minimal spanning tree and count number edges in it. If the difference is `k` then `yes`, else `no`

Comment: The above methods still works. Only this time you have to check if the difference is less than or equal to `k` or not

Comment: @banarun: I'm not really sure that I understand you. Why would there be only one minimum spanning tree? Also, I've changed the question to "at most k edges" if that changes something in your answer.

Comment: Even if there are multiple, the number of edges won't change.

Comment: @banarun Wrong on all counts.  There are generally many spanning trees.  A minimum spanning tree is not just any spanning tree.

Comment: @btilly There will be V-1 edges for any spanning trees.

Comment: @btilly: did someone say there is just one spanning tree?

Comment: @banarun: your method doesn't work. MST always contains e.g. the smallest edge, so if `e` is such edge the answer is always yes.

Comment: @n.m. the question is about trying to get `yes` when it is possible.

Comment: @banarun: your method fails to get yes when it is possible. Draw a quadrangle with diagonals, that's your graph. Set `k`=1, mark the shortest side `e`. The correct answer is `yes`. Your method says `no` because `|E|-k>|V|-1`. Sorry about pointing out the obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: for every edge e, there exists a minimum-weight spanning forest containing e if and only if there exists no path between e's endpoints comprised of edges (strictly) lighter than e.

Comment: I think I got it: By your comment, we can remove at most k edges so there will exist such a minimum weight spanning forest iff we can remove at most k edges so that there will be not path between the enpoint of e comprised of edges lighter than e. Thus we build a flow net so that the source is one endpoint of e, the sink is the other, we include all the vertices and edges that are lighter than e (each edge become two, one in each direction with weight 1) and than we check the maximum flow of this graph. If it's smaller or equlas to k we return  "yes", otherwise "no". Is it correct?

Comment: @Roy Yep. If I were grading this and feeling picky, I'd look also for a proof that your chosen removals don't disconnect the graph, since the question asked for a spanning *tree*, not a forest.